# Additional Examples of Quantum and Classical Analogs?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, semiclassical

I was wondering if there are any other important classical/quantum analogs, along the lines of these examples:

- Schrödinger Equation $\leftrightarrow$ Hamilton-Jacobi Formalism
- Path Integrals $\leftrightarrow$ Lagrangian Formalism
- Heisenberg Picture $\leftrightarrow$ Hamiltonian Formalism
- Commutators $\leftrightarrow$ Poisson brackets

Unfortunately, there don't seem to be any easily searchable lists on Google. To clarify, by correspond I mean equivalent in the classical limit, as $\hbar \rightarrow 0$. For example:

- As $\hbar \rightarrow 0$, the S.E. reduces to the H-J equation and a continuity equation.
- As $\hbar \rightarrow 0$, all paths besides the path of least action cancel out.
- As $\hbar \rightarrow 0$, the commutator reduces to the Poisson bracket as detailed here [http://www.stat.ucla.edu/~ywu/Commutator.pdf](http://www.stat.ucla.edu/%7Eywu/Commutator.pdf), which also shows the correspondence between the Hamiltonian Formalism and the Heisenberg picture.

Comment: The issue here is that you are trying to paint this a lot neater than things actually are. Your arrows here don't really mean the same thing in each cases, beyond some vague, superficial notion of 'corresponding'. Quantization and taking the classical limit are not, in general, straightforward processes. This is why we can't simply draw up a list

Comment: There is nothing confusing about the examples I gave, and nothing vague or superficial about the correspondences. The arrows mean precisely the same thing in each. Take the limit where $\hbar \rightarrow 0$. I don't understand your knee-jerk dismissive attitude.

Comment: I have edited my post to specify precisely what I mean by correspond, and to show that $\leftrightarrow$ means the exact same thing in each case.

Comment: Big list questions don't fit the SE model well...

Comment: I've changed the title to more accurately reflect what I'm looking for. Big lists are not the goal, so much as any additional examples beyond those I've mentioned, which may help to shed insight on the idea of taking the "classical limit".

Comment: I think there are too many connections between quantum mechanics and classical mechanics to list. Some important ones that come to mind that aren't on your list are the WKB approximation and how it connects with old quantum theory,  coherent states, and the large number-of-particles limit.

Comment: Also I don't know much about this, but there is a way to formulate classical mechanics in a Hilbert space formalism. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koopman%E2%80%93von_Neumann_classical_mechanics

Comment: Also, decoherence

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I appreciate it! I'll look into what you mentioned. In particular that classical mech can be framed in terms of Hilbert space.